# Lintstaged process is stuck when running rubocop command

Tags: rubocop, lint-staged

I try to lint my .rb files while committing.

Here is my .lintstagedrc file:

```
{
    "*.rb": [
      "bundle exec rubocop --require rubocop-airbnb",
    ]
}
```

Lint-staged is setup with husky.

When I change a .rb file, it tries to run the command but it is stuck.
I tried to run the command with the debug flags on, but I did not see any useful information:

```
lint-staged:bin Running `lint-staged@15.2.0` on Node.js v18.19.0 (darwin) 
....
....
....
....
[COMPLETED] Preparing lint-staged...
[STARTED] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] .lintstagedrc — 3 files
[STARTED] *.rb — 1 file
[STARTED] *.erb — 0 files
[SKIPPED] *.erb — no files
[STARTED] bundle exec rubocop --version
=> Froze
```

What can be the root cause?

Env

- Running lint-staged 15.2.0
- Running node 18.19.0
- Running rubocop-airbnb 6.0.0
- Commands run fine locally
- `bundle exec erblint` & `bundle exec htmlbeautifier` commands go through when added into the lintstagedrc file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was fixed by [v15.2.1](https://github.com/lint-staged/lint-staged/releases/tag/v15.2.1).
Try to update lint-staged.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance running rubocop in server mode? Rubocop will hang if it is running in server mode (see this issue for details: https://github.com/lint-staged/lint-staged/issues/1293).

Try running `rubocop --stop-server` and then try your commit (or `yarn lint-staged`). A coworker had a similar problem, something in their config caused rubocop to automatically start a server in the background, resulting in this issue.